# Replace NewForm, EditForm with visual web part solutions

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-web-part, newform

I have a visual web part that performs same functions as NewForm.aspx in SharePoint.

I can enter data and click save on the visual web part and it saves title field to SharePoint list.

Now I would like to replace the NewForm with visual web part.
In other words when I click on new item the web part page should open.

Answer (score 1):

Create a feature receiver. On activation event use below snippet to change the Page.

```
SPList lst = web.Lists["ListTitle"];
string newUrl = url;
var form = web.GetFile(newUrl);
if (form != null && form.Exists)
{
    lst.DefaultEditFormUrl = newUrl;
    lst.Update();
}
```

Also make sure to create those pages using `Module` and `Elements.xml` file.

Comment: I am not creating list definition etc using VS. I have just created a visual web part and inserted it on a site page. Let me know what do you mean by the above mentioned answer

Comment: Ok if you know the Page URL then you can change the code and hardcode the URL.

Comment: So what about the pages being created using module and elements?..

Comment: That is the best practice. Using that technique you can create the pages and add the webpart as part of deploying the solution. No need to manually create page, add webpart etc.

Comment: Can you please specify the steps. It would be of great help.

Comment: Or if you could provide any links it would be great

Comment: I have written an article a while back on this topic https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/sharepoint-deploy-webpart-page-using-module/

Comment: Cool. I went through this article and I see you are creating a web part page using vs. So I have a question. Do I just add a feature receiver to this project and specify the web part page URL and deploy and this would open up the web part page when I click on new item? Please let me know.. You are of great help

Answer (score 1):

Open the list in Shareoint Designer and create a new NewForm.aspx - we need the old one in case of a problem. Then, using  UI edit, delete the webpart and add yours webpart